# Adding widget to dashboard based on the individual jacoco execution data file( .exec)

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Please refer to below example:
I have a jar file abc.jar. I have deployed the jar on three different tomcat server, namely server1,server2,server3.
I configured jacoco plugin into server1,server2,server3 to generate jacoco execution file namely jacoco1.exec, jacoco2.exec, jacoco3.exec.
I am executing different test cases with these servers and I got jacoco1.exec, jacoco2.exec, jacoco3.exec.

Using jacoco:merge I can club 3 .exec file and using sonar runner I will get the code coverage report on the sonar server.
On the dashboard of the report I will have different widget like Unit test case, Integration test, etc..
That report will give me figures for combined .exec.

Is there any way I can get the figures based on the execution data file?
Like separate widget for the code coverage given by "jacoco1.exec", separate widget for the code coverage given by "jacoco2.exec", separate widget for the code coverage given by "jacoco3.exec"
And combined report as well.  By this I will be able to identify which testing is hitting/missing which code of the jar.
As the jar file is same, I want to create single project on the dashboard, and under that I should get this distributed information. I don't want to create different projects on the Sonar dashboard.
As there any way to achieve this in Sonar Server (3.5.1 V) code coverage report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, as you have only 1 "coverage" measure per project.